# How can do the pf calculation and how to display the total pf amount

Tags: php, mysql

Here I want to PF calculation, we are deducting pf for every month, now I want to display the total pf amount.this is my database table structure

```
id    first_name   pf_amount   pf_month    badge_number

1      Kani         200         01-2017      01

2      Mahesh       250         01-2017      02

3      Kani         200         02-2017      01

4      Mahesh       250         02-2017      02
```

In my list page I want to display badge_number (01) having  400 and badge_number (02) having 500. here badge_number is unique

I wrote the **query** like this but here I am getting all data, how can do bassed on my requirement

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pf_history");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
   echo $row['pf_amount'];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean 'i want to display badge_number (01) having 400' what is 400 here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use GROUP BY AND SUM() in Query:**

```
SELECT first_name, pf_month, SUM(pf_amount) as total FROM pf_history GROUP BY badge_number
```

**Code:**

```
$check = mysqli_query("SELECT first_name, pf_month, SUM(pf_amount) as total FROM pf_history GROUP BY badge_number");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check)) {
  echo $row['total'];
}
```

**Reference** for group by and sum():

[GROUP BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)

[SUM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: nice but let the op know that mysql_ is deprecated, he is probably new to php

Comment: @JapanGuy oh yes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sum()` and `group by` as follow:

```
SELECT first_name, pf_month, badge_number, SUM(pf_amount) as total_pf_amount
FROM pf_history 
GROUP BY badge_number
```

PHP:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, pf_month, badge_number, SUM(pf_amount) as total_pf_amount
    FROM pf_history 
    GROUP BY badge_number");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
    echo $row['total_pf_amount'];
}
```

[reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)